# Need to expand the uitableviewcell in both directions

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have implemented a pinch gesture on the cells of the tablebiew. On pinching, the cell expands(I increase the cell height), but the increase is towards bottom direction.

I want to have the cell expansion towards top direction as well so that it pushes the cell before it towards top.

Is it possible in ios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only increase the height downwards, but wherever you increase the height, change the contentOffset of the tableview so the content scrolls up by half the increase in height. That way the cell will appear to expanding above and below. Once the pinch stops, remember to restore the contentOffset to CGSizeZero if the contentSize is smaller than the bounds of the table view.

Comment: when you change the contentOffset to zero after pinch stops, I think scrolling animation will show for contentOffset changed. So won't it affect the user experience??

Comment: You can change contentOffset without animating it. Just call `[myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO]`.

Comment: is it possible to scroll the tableview by some offset rather than ba specifying to which location it should scroll? for eg:- [sampleTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,100) animated:NO] scroll the tableview to the y position 100, but i want the tableview to scroll by value 100.

Comment: well you can access the current content offset using `sampleTableView.contentOffset`, so if you wanted to simply increment the y offset by 100 you could do something like `[sampleTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(sampleTableView.contentOffset.x, sampleTableView.contentOffset.y + 100) animated:NO]`.

Comment: Thanks, I exactly did the same thing and everything works fine for me.